# What technologies was used to created SMS spoof applications?

Tags: mobile, sms

I have a client that would like to start a SMS spoof application. I have seen it be done before, and I am wondering where would I start to achieve this?

Comment: Can you provide more details of what you're after? Should this be on a phone? if so what sort?

Answer (score 0):

I don´t understand your question perfectly, but you should look at [SMPP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_message_peer-to-peer_protocol), although [HTTP APIs](https://labs.ericsson.com/apis/sms-send-and-receive/documentation) are mostly used too, and [Kannel](http://www.kannel.org/).